# Why doesn't xrandr recognize my view as connected, even though it's on?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo, xrandr

I have a dual screen setup via a Lenovo docking station, the laptop itself has its lid shut. The two screens are mirror display, i.e. both are clearly on and working to some extent, they both display the same exact content. When I type `xrandr` I get the following:

```
eDP1 connected ...
DP1 disconnected
HDMI1 disconnected
DP2 connected ...
HDMI2 disconnected
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
```

So only two displays are apparently available, the eDP1 is the laptop screen, the DP2, I guess is associated with the docking station instead of individual monitors. Turning off one monitor makes the whole setup go terribly wrong. I am trying to get an extended view but can't seem to figure out how. I've tried installing the latest Intel Graphic Drivers, since that's what the machine uses, but that hasn't particularly helped. Is there anything else I should look into?

Comment: Can you use `arandr`?

Comment: Same deal, it doesn't detect the existence of a second monitor